# SharePoint Modern Hub Site - unable to Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature-activation, modern-experience, communication-site, hub-site

I have a SharePoint Hub site and I have created a sub-site using the Records Center template.

With this being so, I have attempted to Activate "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**" under Site Collection Features.

> This fails with the error: Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected
> error has occurred.  Correlation ID:
> 9058729e-60c2-6000-8a68-2afd92bbd61c
>
> Date and Time: 6/18/2018 7:46:08 AM

Microsoft support haven't been particularly helpful with this issue and just tell me it should work.

At the worst I can setup the Record Center site as a new site and then bind it to the Modern Hub Site if necessary.

*Would just like clarification on whether enabling this feature is supported under Modern sites?*

Answer (score 1):

Classic publishing features are not supported in Modern sites. These sites are `NoScript` sites by default.

What's not supported on "modern" team sites -

> -Custom master pages; more extensive branding will be supported later
> using alternative options.
> -Enabling site or site collection scoped
> publishing features; technically, features can be currently activated,
> but this is not a supported configuration.
>
> -Classic publishing features (WCM)

Reference to Microsoft Docs - [Supported customizations on "modern" team sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#supported-customizations-on-modern-team-sites)

Comment: seems a bit silly considering the subsite is in itself a classic site.

Comment: MS is pushing for a flat structure, which means if you want to use Modern sites, then you shouldnt be using subsites , just create new site collections. If you want to use classic features, then using subsites makes sense

Comment: If I use this script it would enable these features.

$scurl = "https://TENANT NAME.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE NAME"
$AdminURL = "https://TENANT NAME-admin.sharepoint.com"
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminURL
Set-SPOSite -Identity $scUrl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, technically it is possible but not supported in modern sites. The publishing pages, in my experience, dont play nice on modern sites, i usually avoid them

Comment: This will work when you create a modern team site. Choosing the second option for creating a Communication site doesnt allow the publishing feature to be activated.

Answer (score 0):

This will work when you create a modern team site. Choosing the second option for creating a Communication site doesnt allow the publishing feature to be activated