# Can not Activate SharePoint Server Publishing feature in communication site of O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, communication-site

I just trying to activate SharePoint Server Publishing using Manage site features to be able to use Content editor web part. I found the following Error:

NB:

SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is already activated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need Publishing, use a classic Publishing site or classic Team site with Publishing enabled.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-publishing-features-479677A6-8B33-4AC7-907D-071C1C7E4518

Comment: Bad news, How do i get access to be able to use content editor web part to inject Javascript on my communication site ?

Comment: See the guidance at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#supported-customizations-on-modern-team-sites. Similar question is at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243613/sharepoint-modern-hub-site-unable-to-activate-sharepoint-server-publishing-inf.